# How do I prevent NSMutableArray from losing data?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

The first view of my app is a UITableView.

The user will choose an option and the next view will be another UITableView.  Now the user can tap on an "add" button to be taken to another UIViewController to enter text in a UITextField.  That text will then appear in the previous UITableViewCell when saved.

The issue I am having: if I back out to the main view and then go back to where I previously was, that inputed text is now gone.

How can I make sure that text is not being released or disappears like this?

Comment: you should have a data model somewhere in your app (a singleton instance or perhaps an object associated with your application instance or app delegate) that saves the information, separately from your controller code...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to store this array somewhere else in your project, like in an MVC (data model). You could create a new class for it that passes the information through the classes and stores the array in one place. Then once you add to the array, you could reference that class and call a method in that class to store the text in the array and whenever you load the table view it loads with that array in the class.

In my case, I would do this, but I would make everything class methods (where you cannot access properties or ivars) and just store the array in the user defaults / web service or wherever you need and retrieve and add/return it like this:

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)arrayOfSavedData {

    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"savedData"];
}

+ (void)addStringToArray: (NSString *)stringFromTextField {

   [[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"savedData"] mutableCopy] addObject: stringFromTextField];

}
```

The `mutableCopy` part is important because arrays don't stay mutable after you store them into the user defaults

Answer (score 0):

The reason the text is gone, is probably because you're instantiating new controllers when you go back to where you were. You can keep a strong reference to your controllers, and only instantiate one if it doesn't exist yet. Exactly how to do this depends on how you're moving between controllers -- whether you're doing it in code, or using a storyboard for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue is very frequent. When you move around multiple controllers and views.

Each time you load a new view and controllers are alloc+init, new set of values are assigned and previous values are not used!!!.

You can use SharedInstance/SingletonClass so that it is allocated & assigned once and does not get re created with new set of values.